# xp_dirtree with a while loop on a file count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to write a stored procedure that loops through its self until a set file count is met, then it moves on. However since i create a temp table with the result I haven't been able to get this into a cursors of while loop.

Here is the query to get the files

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #1
CREATE TABLE #1 (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
      ,depth int
      ,isfile bit);

 INSERT #1 
EXEC xp_dirtree '\\ServerName\File_BackUp\CSV\', 10, 1
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM #1;
```

Is it possible to wrap this so it keeps looping until the count hits 10?

Answer (score 0):

A `WHILE` should work just fine here.  Try:

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM #1 < 10)
BEGIN
    INSERT #1
    EXEC xp_dirtree '\\ServerName\File_BackUp\CSV\', 10, 1
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'    -- Wait five seconds between checks
                                -- so you don't flog your machine badly.
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like some kind of integration scenario (checking directory for incoming files).

If your case depends heavily on moving files, transformations, loading and so on
I suggest to use proper tool for this like SQL Server Integration Services.

You could easily build `FileWatcher` task:

[Developing a File Watcher Task for SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4668/developing-a-file-watcher-task-for-sql-server-integration-services/)

or use 3rd party one:

[Using the Konesans File Watcher Task in SSIS to Process Data Files](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/91068/)

> **[File Watcher Task](http://www.konesans.com/products/file-watcher-task)**
>
> File Watcher Task does what it says really, it watches a folder waiting for files. When an available file is found the task completes, returning the name of the file for onward use within the package.